# Javabean Where to put the bean class file?

Tags: java

I have a javabean file that is written to collect user data from web form. (UserData.java)

This file is compiled and is put under a package called `user`
(I put this class under `webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\user`)

Then in a particular html page, I allow user to enter their name, email, etc.
When user clicks on the submit button they will go to "/process.jsp", in which the first two statements are:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.UserData" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*" />
```

But it throws:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /process.jsp(1,1) The value for the useBean class attribute user.UserData is invalid.
```

Notice that my UserData is a public class and the getter and setter methods are correct.

Can anyone help?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. Your UserData should have a no argument constructor, though by default its present but if provided a parameterized constructor you will have to provide it explicitly.
2. Package is exactly the same like

   package user;
   public class UserData {

   }

and not

```
package User;
public class UserData {

}
```

3. Your class has compiled correctly doesn't contain any compilation error.

Comment: 1. Yes. UserData has no-arg constructor
2. Yes. `package user`, not `package User`
3. No error

Comment: Is your jsp also part of ROOT or any other webapp ?